# How do I add a dropdown menu that when you select an option and click send it shows the option in the email?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, html-email

I have a website that I am making and I am adding a email portion that emails me their email and their message. I want to add another section that is a dropdown. It will have the three different pricing options, basic, pro, and premium. Then, whichever option they selected is put into the email so I can see it at the bottom of it. here is the code I have so far:

```
<form action="https://postmail.invotes.com/send"
    method="post" id="email_form">

    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Email" />
    <textarea name="text" placeholder="Message">
      
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="0i7j9jp18jinjtx8mhlqvg8k" />
      <!-- return urls can be fully qualified -OR-
         start with / for root relative -OR-
         start with . for url relative --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value=".?message=Email+Successfully+Sent%21&isError=0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value=".?message=Email+could+not+be+sent.&isError=1" />
   

    <!-- set the reply-to address -->
    <!-- <input type="text" name="reply_to"
                placeholder="Your Email" /> -->

    <!-- to append extra fields, use the extra_ prefix.
        Entries will be appended to your message body. -->
    <!-- <input type="text" name="extra_phone_number"
                placeholder="Phone Number" /> -->

    <!-- to split your message into 160 chars
         for an sms gateway -->
    <!-- <input type="hidden"
                name="sms_format" value="true" /> -->
   
    <input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Send" />
    <!-- not required, but we'd appreciate it if you'd link to us somewhere on your site -->
    <p>Powered by <a href="https://postmail.invotes.com" target="_blank">PostMail</a></p>
</form>
     
<!-- optional, prevents the submit button from being pressed more than once -->
<script>
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit_form");
    var form = document.getElementById("email_form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            submitButton.value = "Sending...";
            submitButton.disabled = true;
        }, 1);
    });
</script> 
<style>/* Style inputs with type="text", select elements and textareas */
input[type=text], select, textarea {
   width: 100%; /* Full width */
   padding: 12px; /* Some padding */ 
   border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
   border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
   box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
  margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
  margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
  resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
 }

 /* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
   color: white;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 4px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 /* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
 input[type=submit]:hover {
   background-color: #45a049;
 }

 /* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
 .container {
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   padding: 20px;
 }</style>
```

Comment: Where's your server-side code?

Comment: that is the server side code. i am using a website to send the mail

Comment: @GetSet the server side code is on a website that I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your dropdown inside the form, then when it's time to submit, intercept that and append the dropdown value to the user's text.

For this SOLUTION, I do the interception by not having a button that sends the form to the server directly. Instead a script is called on it's behalf to then append the dropdown value.

All other explanations are in the code comments.

```js
function validateThenSend() {
    // Write a script that appends the "plan" to the message body, then sends the form to the server.
  
    // Optional validation code
    // ...
    
    // If validated, then continue:
    
    // Append the user selected Plan to the textarea.
    
    var curText = document.getElementById("text").value;
    curText += "\n\nPLAN: " + document.getElementById("plans").value;
    document.getElementById("text").value = curText;
    
    // Submit the form
    
    // Uncomment the next line for the actual Send.
    // I have it commented for testing here in SO.
    
    // document.getElementById("email_form").submit();
    
}
```

```html
<form action="https://postmail.invotes.com/send"
    method="post" id="email_form">

    <!-- Add in your dropdown, and give it an id but it wont need a name attribute -->
    
    <select id="plans">
        <option value="Plan 1">Plan 1</option>
        <option value="Plan 2">Plan 2</option>
        <option value="Plan 3">Plan 3</option>
    </select>
    
    <br/>
    <br/>
    
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Email" />
    
    <br/>
    <br/>
    
    
    <!-- Give the textarea an id -->
    <textarea name="text" placeholder="Message" id="text" cols=30 rows=10></textarea>
    
    <input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="0i7j9jp18jinjtx8mhlqvg8k" />
      <!-- return urls can be fully qualified -OR-
         start with / for root relative -OR-
         start with . for url relative --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value=".?message=Email+Successfully+Sent%21&isError=0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value=".?message=Email+could+not+be+sent.&isError=1" />
   

    <!-- set the reply-to address -->
    <!-- <input type="text" name="reply_to"
                placeholder="Your Email" /> -->

    <!-- to append extra fields, use the extra_ prefix.
        Entries will be appended to your message body. -->
    <!-- <input type="text" name="extra_phone_number"
                placeholder="Phone Number" /> -->

    <!-- to split your message into 160 chars
         for an sms gateway -->
    <!-- <input type="hidden"
                name="sms_format" value="true" /> -->
   
    <!-- hide your Send button or simply remove it -->
    <input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Send" style="display:none"/> 
    
    <!-- Make a fake Send button the user will see. -->
    <button type="button" onclick="validateThenSend()">Send</button>
    
    <!-- not required, but we'd appreciate it if you'd link to us somewhere on your site -->
    <p>Powered by <a href="https://postmail.invotes.com" target="_blank">PostMail</a></p>
</form>
```